# A dictionary with a single value and multiple keys

Tags: kdb, k

What are the dictionaries with a single value and multiple keys stands for?
What are their purposes?

I've accidentally created one, but can not do anything with it:

```
q)type (`a`b`c)!(`d)
99h
q)((`a`b`c)!(`d))[`a]
'par
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That special form usually denotes the flip of a partitioned table, where the keys represent the column names and the value represents the table name:

```
q)/load a database with partitioned table part_tab
q)flip part_tab
`ncej`jogn`ciha`hkpb`aeaj`blmj`ooei`jgjm`cflm`bpmc!`part_tab
```

This dictionary is not intended to be looked up in the usual manner and not in the way that you've attempted.

It would be completely ill-advised but it is possible to restrict columns of a partitioned table by manipulating this dictionary:

```
q)select from part_tab where date=2020.01.02
date       ncej jogn ciha hkpb aeaj blmj ooei jgjm cflm bpmc
------------------------------------------------------------
2020.01.02 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2020.01.02 1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
2020.01.02 2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
2020.01.02 3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
...

q)part_tab:flip`ncej`jogn`ciha!`part_tab
q)select from part_tab where date=2020.01.02
date       ncej jogn ciha
-------------------------
2020.01.02 0    0    0
2020.01.02 1    1    1
2020.01.02 2    2    2
...
```

Again don't try this on any large/production tables, it's an undocumented quirk.

Splay table have a similar dictionary when flipped:

```
q)flip splay
`ncej`jogn`ciha`hkpb`aeaj`blmj`ooei`jgjm`cflm`bpmc!`:splay/
```

The difference being that the table name has a "/" at the end and is `hsym`'d. This is how `.Q.qp` determines if a table is partitioned or splayed.

Comment: Thank you Terry! It even works for `':splay/ set ([]a:1 2;b:3 4;c:5 6); flip 'b'c!':splay` - without tailing `/` in the `!` clause.